# How to point to the correct element with jQuery selector if multiple ones exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, youtube-api

I'm having difficulty selecting an element in the html using jQuery selector. I'm creating a categorized filter with the checkboxes and video tags. I'm trying to figure how to have a unique identifier for each of the video thumbnail elements that show/hide based on its video tags and if the checkboxes are checked. I have a function that basically gets video tags from another function that loops through each video and pulls its tag array values like so:

```
// print the results
        function(data)
        {
            var output;

            $.each(data.items, 
                function(i, item) 
                {
                    var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title
                    var vidDesc = item.snippet.description; // video description
                    var videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; // video id
                    var vidThumbUrl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url; // video thumbnail url
                    getVideoDuration(videoId).done(function(duration, view/*, tags*/)
                    {
                        vidDuration = duration;

                        viewCount = view;

                        //vidTags = tags;


                        // check if video tags is empty or undefined 
                        if(typeof videoTags === 'undefined' || videoTags == "" || videoTags === null)
                        {
                            videoTags = "No tags have been defined for this video.";
                        }


                        // check input categories
                        validateCategory(videoTags);


                        console.log("id: " + videoId + " duration: " + convert_time(vidDuration) + " viewCount: " + viewCount + ' videoTags: ' + videoTags); // return value in console
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                        console.log("<br>");


                        output = '<li><iframe height="' + vidHeight + '" width="' + vidWidth + '" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '\"></iframe></li><div id="title">' + vidTitle + '</div><div id="desc">' + vidDesc + '</div><div id="duration">Length: ' + convert_time(vidDuration) + '</div><div id="stats">View Count: ' + viewCount + '</div><div id="tags">Tags: ' + videoTags + '</div>';

                        // if video title is longer than 25 characters, insert the three-dotted ellipse
                        if(vidTitle.length > 25)
                        {
                            var strNewVidTitle = vidTitle.substr(0, 25) + "...";
                            vidTitle = strNewVidTitle;
                        }
                        var vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '"><div class="video-overlay"><img src="imgs/video-play-button.png"/></div><img id="thumb" src="' + vidThumbUrl + '" alt="No Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"/></a><p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '">' + vidTitle + '</a><br/>' + convert_time(vidDuration) + ' / Views: ' + viewCount + '</p></div>';


                        // append results
                        $('#results').append(output);
                        $('#thumb').append(vidThumbnail);


                    }); // end of getVideoDuration(videoId).done
                }
            ); // end of getViewCount(videoId).done
        }
```

Now, when checkbox is set to checked, it will check the `input` attribute `value="reading"` and if it matches the tag, to set the `.video-thumbnail` class div attribute to `rel="reading"` to uniquely identify and categorize each video. This is what I attempted so far:

```
// show/hide categorized videos
function validateCategory(videoTags) // TODO: add videoId to make an unique identifier for said video thumbnail.
{
    // check if input category is or isn't checked and omit videos not matching checked categories
    if($('input[value="reading"]').is(':checked'))
    {
        console.log('%c reading: ' + ".is(':checked'):", 'color:blue;'); // check if 'pregnancy' is checked
        for(i = 0; i < videoTags.length; i++)
        {
            if(videoTags[i] === "reading".trim().toLowerCase())
            {
                $('.video-thumbnail', this).css({visibility:'visible'});
                $('.video-thumbnail', this).show();
                $('.video-thumbnail', this).attr('rel','reading'); // set rel attribute according to tag name as a unique identifier
                $('.video-thumbnail', this).css({backgroundColor:'red'});
            }
            else
            {
                $('.video-thumbnail', this).css({visibility:'hidden'});
                $('.video-thumbnail', this).hide();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $('.video-thumbnail', this).css({visibility:'hidden'});
        $('.video-thumbnail', this).hide();
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Youtube Videos</h1>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
    <hr/>
    <h1>Thumbnails</h1>
    <div id="thumb"></div>
    <div id="category-list" class="getFixed">
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <input class="categories" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Reading" checked>Reading<br/>
        <input class="categories" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Math" checked>Math<br/>
        <input class="categories" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="Science" checked>Science
    </div>
</div>
```

The `validateCategory(...)` function will loop through successfully, but it won't refer the jQuery Selector to use `this` video thumbnail class to show/hide certain videos from category when checked/unchecked like a category filter. I even did background color and visibility but nothing works. I'm trying to figure out how to link the two and two together.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this` is referring to the `window` object from within your `validateCategory()` function. The window object doesn't have direct access to the dom, so you would need to use `this.document` or just `document`. But, I don't think you want to refer to the entire document in this case. Doing so will make changes to every member of the `.video-thumbnail` class on each iteration. I would think you want to call this function after you have built your `vidThumbnail div` for each entry, and pass this div as an argument:

```
    function(data)
    {
        var output;

        $.each(data.items, 
            function(i, item) 
            {
                var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title
                var vidDesc = item.snippet.description; // video description
                var videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; // video id
                var vidThumbUrl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url; // video thumbnail url
                getVideoDuration(videoId).done(function(duration, view/*, tags*/)
                {
                    vidDuration = duration;

                    viewCount = view;

                    //vidTags = tags;


                    // check if video tags is empty or undefined 
                    if(typeof videoTags === 'undefined' || videoTags == "" || videoTags === null)
                    {
                        videoTags = "No tags have been defined for this video.";
                    }

                    console.log("id: " + videoId + " duration: " + convert_time(vidDuration) + " viewCount: " + viewCount + ' videoTags: ' + videoTags); // return value in console
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                    console.log("<br>");


                    output = '<li><iframe height="' + vidHeight + '" width="' + vidWidth + '" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '\"></iframe></li><div id="title">' + vidTitle + '</div><div id="desc">' + vidDesc + '</div><div id="duration">Length: ' + convert_time(vidDuration) + '</div><div id="stats">View Count: ' + viewCount + '</div><div id="tags">Tags: ' + videoTags + '</div>';

                    // if video title is longer than 25 characters, insert the three-dotted ellipse
                    if(vidTitle.length > 25)
                    {
                        var strNewVidTitle = vidTitle.substr(0, 25) + "...";
                        vidTitle = strNewVidTitle;
                    }
                    var vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '"><div class="video-overlay"><img src="imgs/video-play-button.png"/></div><img id="thumb" src="' + vidThumbUrl + '" alt="No Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"/></a><p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '">' + vidTitle + '</a><br/>' + convert_time(vidDuration) + ' / Views: ' + viewCount + '</p></div>';

                    // check input categories
                    validateCategory(videoTags, vidThumbnail);

                    // append results
                    $('#results').append(output);
                    $('#thumb').append(vidThumbnail);


                }); // end of getVideoDuration(videoId).done
            }
        ); // end of getViewCount(videoId).done
    }


function validateCategory(videoTags, vidThumbnail) // TODO: add videoId to make an unique identifier for said video thumbnail.
{
    // check if input category is or isn't checked and omit videos not matching checked categories
    if($('input[value="reading"]').is(':checked'))
    {
        console.log('%c reading: ' + ".is(':checked'):", 'color:blue;'); // check if 'pregnancy' is checked
        for(i = 0; i < videoTags.length; i++)
        {
            if(videoTags[i] === "reading".trim().toLowerCase())
            {
                $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).css({visibility:'visible'});
                $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).show();
                $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).attr('rel','reading'); // set rel attribute according to tag name as a unique identifier
                $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).css({backgroundColor:'red'});
            }
            else
            {
                $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).css({visibility:'hidden'});
                $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).hide();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).css({visibility:'hidden'});
        $('.video-thumbnail', vidThumbnail).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work. Still the same results.

Comment: What is it you are seeing? Depending on the order of the tags in your `videoTags` list, you should break the for-loop once "reading" is found to avoid having the element hidden again.

Comment: I'm not seeing any changes even with `break;` inside the `if(videoTags[i] === "Reading".trim().toLowerCase()){}` statement.